# Datepicker with enabled dates form calender

Tags: jquery, solspace-calendar

I'm trying to create a jquery datepicker with the available dates form the module Calender from solspace.

The problem is when i add the data manualy to the variable it works, but when i thy to use the dates form calendar i get a empty datepicker.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Here is my javascript code.

```
var datums = '{exp:calendar:cal  event_limit="{embed:event_limit}" date_range_start="today" show_weeks="12" pad_short_weeks="n" dynamic="off"}"{event_start_date format="%d-%n-%Y"}",{/exp:calendar:cal}';
var datums2 = [datums.substring(0, datums.length -1)];
var unavailableDates = datums2;

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        return [true, ""];   
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#book-date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: 0, 
        maxDate: "+6M"
    });
});
```

Comment: And what does the JS look like when it renders in your template (specifically `var datums`)?

Comment: In the source code i have this information:
var datums = '"17-12-2013","18-12-2013","19-12-2013","20-12-2013","21-12-2013","24-12-2013","28-12-2013","31-12-2013","01-1-2014","02-1-2014","03-1-2014","04-1-2014","07-1-2014","08-1-2014","09-1-2014","10-1-2014","11-1-2014","14-1-2014","15-1-2014","16-1-2014","17-1-2014","18-1-2014","21-1-2014","22-1-2014","23-1-2014","24-1-2014","25-1-2014","28-1-2014","29-1-2014","30-1-2014","31-1-2014","01-2-2014","04-2-2014","05-2-2014","06-2-2014","07-2-2014","08-2-2014",';
THe last , i remove in the var datums2

Comment: And what errors, if any, do you see in the javascript console in your browser?

Comment: I don't get any errors. I get a empty datepicker, It looks like the loop isn't loping. 

You can check the site: dev.carinatapas.nl. When you clcik on the red button "Reserveer nu" you get a form and when you click on the "Datum" field, the datepicker appears.